# Laravel Jetstream seeder null value in column "team_id" of relation "model_has_roles"

Tags: php, laravel

Good day
I would like help with the following.

I'm trying to seed an admin using Laravel Seeder (db:seed) but I keep getting an error.
here is my seeder class

```
 public function run(): void
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::create([
            'name' => 'Topollo Raliqala',
            'email' => 'topollo@babatle.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('asDF1@#ASdf'),
        ]);

        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'Admin']);

        $permissions = Permission::pluck('id', 'id')->all();

        $role->syncPermissions($permissions);

        $user->ownedTeams()->save(\App\Models\Team::forceCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => "Babatle (Pty) Ltd",
            'personal_team' => false,
        ]));

        $user->assignRole([$role->id]);
    }
```

I get this error and I can't figure out where to add the team_id

[image]

It gives this error when it comes to relationship but it does add the user, team and the role.

I'm using Laravel 10
spatie/laravel-permission

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "team_id" of relation "model_has_roles" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, App\Models\User, 1, null). (Connection: pgsql, SQL: insert into "model_has_roles" ("model_id", "model_type", "role_id", "team_id") values (1, App\Models\User, 1, ?))
```

Comment: Which exact line is giving you the error?

Comment: I think is this one ```$user->assignRole([$role->id]);``` since it is the last one and I'm assigning a user to a role therefore the many to many relationship record is created and records are inserted in model_has_roles

Comment: The issue is the team_id

Answer (score 1):

I added this line of code and it worked now

```
setPermissionsTeamId($team->id);
```

Updated code

```
public function run(): void
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::create([
            'name' => 'user',
            'email' => 'user@babatle.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('fgsdf123'),
            'email_verified_at' => time(),
        ]);

        $role = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);

        $permissions = Permission::pluck('id', 'id')->all();

        $role->syncPermissions($permissions);

        $team = \App\Models\Team::forceCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => "Babatle (Pty) Ltd",
            'personal_team' => true,
        ]);

        $user->ownedTeams()->save($team);

        $team->users()->attach(
            $user->id,
            ['role' => 'admin']
        );

        setPermissionsTeamId($team->id);

        $user->assignRole('admin');
    }
```

I don't understand it so please if you have an explanation do add it.
It filled teams, users, role_has_permissions, model_has_roles and team_user
[image]

[image]
[image]

but if set personal_team to false, I get this error `Attempt to read property "name" on null` pointing to currentTeam->name in navbar

It works turns out I wrote admin with Capital letter A so I was supposed to use a small letter a